# sqlstate=42000 on sqlconnect (HDBC),Login failed

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting the below error while connecting the sql server through unix box, i have created the DSN for the sql server and passing the user id and pass word to connect the sql server,
here is the error

> SQLSTATE=42000 ON SQLCONNECT(HDBC) DIAGNOSTIC=[FreeTDS] [SQL SERVER]
>   Login Failed.

Comment: Please, check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

Comment: Any other possible ways ??